# Make xsd.exe generate files in russian doll style

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I'm trying to use xsd.exe to generate a schema for my assembly. I'm fairly new to xsd but I know I'd like the design style of the file to be in the "russian doll" style, with no global components or types except of course the root element. In fact all of the elements being local would be the best for me. The xsd.exe tool seems to generate a file that advocates high component reusability, probably "salami slice" or some of the other design patterns similar to it.

Is there a way to specify some options when generating the schema so that it follows the russian doll style? If not, is there a tool that will generate xsd this way?

Answer (score 0):

Russian Doll is a simple schema design which you can do yourself without xsd.exe using the idea that there is only one root element everything else inside it .
Read the below example to know more :

```
<xs:schema>
<xs:element name="HelpDoc">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>    
<xs:element name="Section">    
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>    
 <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string"/>    
 <xs:element name="Body" type="xs:string"/>
 </xs:sequence>
 <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
 </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
 </xs:sequence>
  <xs:/complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

Link here : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-schemascope/

Comment: I'm pretty sure he knows that the style is.  The question is how to generate it from an assembly using a tool like Microsoft's xsd.exe